# Cache distribution exercise as presented at googles HashCode 2017

Tags: algorithm, sorting, optimization, combinatorics

I'm currently trying to find an efficient solution to the problem stated in this document [Hash Code 2017 - Streaming Videos](https://hashcode.withgoogle.com/2017/tasks/hashcode2017_qualification_task.pdf).

> **TLDR;** To minimize latency of youtube videos, cache serves with limited
>   capacity are used. However not every cache is connected to every
>   endpoint and not every entpoint requests the same videos. The goal is
>   to minimize overall latency of the whole network.

[image: simplified model of the cache architecture]

My approach was to simply iterate through each endpoint and each requests block and find the optimal cache with the most **latency reduction** per video size *(I'll just call it **request density**)*.

When the optimal cache has already reached its capacity, I try to store it in exchange for videos with less **request density** or use a different cache if there is no other possibility *(notice that the data center is also a cache in my model)*.

```
def distribute_video_requests(endpoint, excluding_caches=set()):
    caches = endpoint.cache_connections - excluding_caches

    for vr in endpoint.video_requests:
        optimal_cache = find_optimum(caches, vr)

        exchange = try_put(optimal_cache, vr)

        if exchange["conflicting"]:
            excluding_caches.add(optimal_cache)

            for elm in exchange["affected"]:
                distribute_video_requests(elm["from"], excluding_caches)


for ep in endpoints:
    distribute_video_requests(ep)
```

You could visualize it as [Brazil nut effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granular_convection) where the video requests are pieces with different density which are sorted in a stack.

The reason I'm explaining all of this is because I can't realy tell if my solution is decent and if it isn't: what are better approaches for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somebody gives you a proposed solution, one thing you could do is pick on one of the cache servers, empty it, and then try and work out the best way to fill it up to get a solution at least as good as the proposed one.

I think this is the knapsack problem, so it will not be easy to find an efficient exact solution to this, or to the original problem.

There are decent approximations to the knapsack problem so I think it might be worth programming it up and throwing it at the solutions from your method. If it can't improve on the original solution much, congratulations! If it can, you have another solution method - keep running the knapsack problem to adjust the contents of each cache server until you can't find any more improvements.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually solved this problem using basic OOP, stream based data reading and writing, and basic loops.

My solution is infact available at: https://github.com/TheBlackPlague/YouTubeCache .

The solution is coded in PHP just because I wanted an interpreted language to do this quickly in rather than a compiled one. However, this can easily be extended to any language to speed up execution times.